# while function and if statement returning incorrectly in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using the following code to list all the posts in my wordpress website and I am trying to call "selected" if the ID is the current cone selected but strangely it's calling the if statement 3 times rather than once even though all the ID's are different.

My Code:

```
function test($id) {
    // The Query
    query_posts( array ('posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
    // The Loop
     while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); 
     if ($id == get_the_ID()) { $selected = " selected"; }
     ?>
    <option value="<?php echo get_the_ID(); ?>"<?php echo $selected; ?>><?php echo get_the_title() ?></option><?php echo "\n"; ?>
    <?php endwhile;
    // Reset Query
    wp_reset_query();
    }
```

My Output:

```
<select name="w_url">
<option value="493">TEST 1</option>
<option value="390">TEST 2</option>
<option value="388" selected>Test 3</option>
<option value="386" selected>Test 4</option>
<option value="384" selected>Test 5</option>
</select>
```

I did select the third option and so it is showing that one correctly but carries on to the 4th and 5th. I'm sure its something simple but I can't see it

Answer (score 2):

After your variable `$selected` gets the value "selected", it doesn't change value in futher iterations. You should use something like

```
if ($id == get_the_ID()) { 
    $selected = " selected"; 
} else { 
    $selected = ""; 
}
```

Comment: Wow do I feel stupid! I should have noticed that! Thank you for such a quick response